# Laravel unique rule on update ignore current id different models same table

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-7

First of all, I know this has been asked millions of times and I have checked every question out, but I cannot figure something out. For a long time I have been using the rule in my FormRequest like below:

```
'name' => 'unique:accounts,name,' . $this->account->id
```

This has always worked like a charm, no problems whatsoever. Just recently I added a few models that are using the same table: `accounts`. Each model has it's own controller and it's own FormRequest, but the above rule is unchanged, it is the same in all the FormRequests. So the main model is called `Account` and the table is called `accounts`. When updating an existing account, and leaving the name untouched, it will update without giving me any errors.

Now, I have another model called `Asset`. When updating an `Asset`, I do the exact same as with the `Account` like I was doing before. But every time I get an error saying the name is already taken, it has to be unique. While it should ignore the row with the given `id`.

I tried hardcoding the `id` like below:

```
'name' => 'unique:accounts,name,1'
```

But it still is giving me the same error. I always thought that the above rule would ALWAYS IGNORE the row with the given `id`. But now I am confused as to how this actually works and how to make it work without having to add more code to my FormRequests.

So my two main questions are:

1. How does the rule work exactly? Why does it not ignore the row with the given id?
2. How can I solve this so it works for all other models, and not only the `Account` model?

Comment: Instead of that, you can use custom validation rule `Rule::unique('table_name')->ignore(1, 'id');` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique

Comment: Thanks, tried that also, same result, it does not ignore the row with `id` 1 :( Or any `id` for that matter..

Comment: i would suppose you have `assets` not `accounts` in the rule?

Comment: Nope, the `Asset` model is using the same table `accounts`, and that is where I think the problem lies but I do not understand why